# Automating process in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, powerpivot

I have an excel spreadsheet that looks at road work licenses and there is a bit of a manual process that I am looking to automate but do not know how to.

The main purpose of the report is to look at licenses issued on a monthly basis and to see which ones have been activated or not. I receive a spreadsheet that shows exactly which licenses have been activated or not.
Each license however has a license number attached to it and there can be multiple licenses with the same license number. For example, license number 10010 can have 15 licenses attached to that one number. Due to a business decision, for these groups of licenses if even one license has been activated from for example, the list of 15, then 1 out of the 15 should be recorded as 'Yes', and the rest as 'N/A' in a separate column, and the rest as 'N/A'. Similarly if all the entries are listed as No, then record one of the licenses as 'No', and the rest as 'N/A'.

There are instances where a group of licenses with the same license number will be recorded as 'No', but if we look at the spreadsheet of the month before, if the same license number shows even 1 license that has been activated from the group, then that same license number from the current month should record one of the license as 'Yes', and the rest as 'N/A'.

There are a few hundred licenses that I have to go through like this monthly, and wanted to know if there is a way to go about it quicker.

I only know how to use excel formulas, but I do not see a way to solve this with an excel formula, but maybe VBA could help, except I do not know any VBA at all, and just wanted to be pushed in the right direction.

Comment: It sure sounds like VBA could help. However, we are here to help out when VBA coders are stuck trying to code something, in your case you seem to be in need of an immediate/quick solution which requires for someone to code something entirely for you, simple or complex. For that there are many websites out there where you can contract hire someone for a project like this. That being said, if you want to learn to code yourself, there are also many websites out there to learn too. The solutions to your problem may be simple enough to learn in a good week of learning VBA. Best of Luck.

Comment: I would try with index() and match() and have two output sheets: "activated" & "waiting" or whatever names work for you.

Comment: Do you know you can record macros? That's an interesting first step to take. Just be aware that the macro recorder has the tendency to mention all parameters, it's up to you to find out which ones you really need. In top of that, far too many selects :-) There are plenty of posts here on the site to explain you how to avoid those. Have fun.